# TabHost : Start the activity without destory other activities

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am using the TabActivity. From the TabActivity I am starting the activity from intent. Order of Activity A - B - C - D then from the activity D, How can I create the same new Activity A (destroy the previous A). If i use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT its does not create the activity, instead open the last Activity A, If I use the Clear_top then it destroy the B and C Activity.

Please help to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are calling Activity `B` from within activity `A`, call `finish()` after creating the new activity `B` using `Intent`. This will end the Activity `A` there. Then again from witin Activity `D` you can create a new Activity `A` using intent. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the TabHost then How can i achieve this?

Comment: You must be using `TabHost` inside a `TabActivity` right? `TabActivity` also extends activity. So it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider destroying the previous activity before calling the next activity 

so when you are going to call the activity B from A you might want to destroy the activity A using the keyword `finish()`
and likewise when you move from `B to C` and `C to D` and in the D activity destroy the activity of C and call the new activity A that way the A activity will get restarted.

```
finish();    //finish the current class
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setClass(getApplicationcontext(), nextclass.class);  //specify the next class
startActivity(intent);      //start the next class.
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

***android:launchMode*** might be the answer you are looking for. From documentation:

`Every time there's a new intent for a "standard" activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that intent. Each instance handles a single intent.`

Means the existing the activity (if exist) will remain in the current stack untouched and new instance will be created at the top of the current stack. So when user back buttons, the user will see your activity A at the bottom of the stack as well.